# Load all Tabs Data at the same at once

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am working with Shell and I have 4 pages, but it doesn't start trying to load the page until after you have clicked into the tab.

Is it possible to have all the tabs in Shell to load at once?

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <Tab  Title="Cotizaciones" Icon="quotation.png" Route="QuotationListPage">
        <ShellContent  Title="Cotizaciones" Icon="quotation.png" Route="QuotationListPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate quotation:QuotationListPage}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="Pedidos" Icon="order.png" Route="OrderListPage">
        <ShellContent Title="Pedidos" Icon="order.png" Route="OrderListPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate order:OrderListPage}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab  Title="Entregas" Icon="delivery.png" Route="DeliveryListPage">
        <ShellContent Title="Entregas" Icon="delivery.png" Route="DeliveryListPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate delivery:DeliveryListPage}"/>
    </Tab>

    <Tab  Title="Solicitudes" Icon="user.png" Route="ClientFormListPage">
        <ShellContent Title="Solicitudes Clientes" Icon="user.png" Route="ClientFormListPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate clientform:ClientFormListPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have all the tabs in Shell to load at once?

For now, it's not.

I use the code you provided for example. This is the default seeting to avoid a poor startup experience.

This XAML creates and displays QuotationListPage, because it's the first item of content declared in the subclassed Shell object. OrderListPage, DeliveryListPage and ClientFormListPage can be navigated to via bottom tabs, and these pages are only created when the user navigates to them. The advantage of this approach is that the poor startup experience is avoided, as pages are created on demand in response to navigation, rather than at application startup.